# When does ssh2_scp_send() return?

Tags: php, ssh

When it has successfully started the transfer, or when it has successfully completed it?  I'd think it would return on completion, but I've run into some old code (yes, of mine :) that thinks that it returns once the transfer has started.  Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the function name implies, it's **sending** via **scp**. 
It returns if it successfully "copies a file from the local filesystem to the remote server using the SCP protocol", 
or doesn't. It will return both ways.

To answer more specifically: It will return when the transfer (*connection via scp*) has finished; whether it failed or succeeded to copy the file over.. **FALSE** and **TRUE** respectively.

Ref:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php